# ASP.NET 4.5 features don't seem available in VS2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, asp.net-4.5

I'm checking out some of the new features in asp.net 4.5, and they don't seem available in VS 2012. Specifically, I was trying out the strongly typed data controls. VS doesn't resolve "Item" in this code block:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
        ModelType="WebApplication2.NorthwindService.Supplier"
        SelectMethod="GetProducts">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
            <ItemTemplate>                    
                <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%# Item.Name %>' />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

If I ignore the red squiggles, I get the following runtime error:

**CS0103: The name 'Item' does not exist in the current context**

Also, at the bottom of the error message, it says this:

**Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.18034**

But if I look at the project properties, under Target Framework, it says 4.5. Under the "About Microsoft Visual Studio" it says:

Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you install the Asp.Net tool chain? It is a separate install from VS2012. http://www.asp.net/downloads

Comment: Yes, I installed the 2012.2 version.

Answer (score 2):

ModelType should be ItemType. this will fix issue you are seeing. :-)